# How to install the printer driver for Canon image running 2520 in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, printing, canon

I unable to install the printer driver in Ubuntu(Ver 13.10) for Canon image running 2520 . please tell the commands .Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Download 2.70 driver: http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100270808.html
2. Uncompress the Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V270_uk_EN.tar.gz
3. Open a terminal, enter the commands (for example for 64-bit system):

   ```
   cd path/64-bit_Driver  
   sudo su  
   dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_2.70-1_amd64.deb  
   dpkg -i cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_2.70-1_amd64.deb  
   /etc/init.d/cups restart  
   /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p CANON-iR2520 -m CNCUPSIR2520ZK.ppd -v lpd://192.168.0.8/CANON-iR2520 -E
   ```

   Please read the README-ufr2-2.7xUK.txt for different printer models.

   ```
   /etc/init.d/cups restart
   ```
4. Open a browser at `//localhost:631`, and add the printer.

Comment: hello, What does "Open a browser at //localhost:631" mean?  Do you mean to past that into firefox http field?

Comment: How can I determine what type in place of "/usr/sbin/lpadmin -p CANON-iR2520 -m CNCUPSIR2520ZK.ppd -v lpd://192.168.0.8/CANON-iR2520 -E  "  ????        I have a CanonMF269dw

Comment: I found my way to a website by clicking README-ufr2-5.6xUS.html    .  Next, i read to type "/usr/sbin/lpinfo -v"   .   I did this.  network ipp
network beh
network https
network ipps
file cups-brf:/
direct hp
network http
network lpd
network socket

direct hpfax
network dnssd://Canon%20MF260._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=01c80000-fe7f-11de-8a39-74bfc08d878b
network socket://192.168.1.4
network ipps://Canon%20MF260._ipps._tcp.local/
    appears. Not sure what to do with this